# How to deserialize nested JSON and tied it to model to represent in view

Tags: asp.net, json, view, model

I am calling RestApi which is giving me Nested JSON in response. I have to handle this nested Json and represent on same Partial View. I will share my model , view and controller code.

I created controller to call api and collect data. Its populating root class but not populating child class

JSON:

```
{
    "id": 98,
    "title": "all numbers",
    "clues_count": 5,
    "clues": [
        {
            "id": 602,
            "answer": "<i>Eight</i>",
            "question": "It was \"enough\" for Dick van Patten",
            "value": 100,
            "airdate": "1984-09-14T12:00:00.000Z",
            "category_id": 98,
            "game_id": null,
            "invalid_count": null
        },
        {
            "id": 608,
            "answer": "16",
            "question": "A teen's \"sweet\" age",
            "value": 200,
            "airdate": "1984-09-14T12:00:00.000Z",
            "category_id": 98,
            "game_id": null,
            "invalid_count": null
        },
        {
            "id": 614,
            "answer": "<i>The Grapes of Wrath</i>",
            "question": "",
            "value": null,
            "airdate": "1984-09-14T12:00:00.000Z",
            "category_id": 98,
            "game_id": null,
            "invalid_count": null
        },
        {
            "id": 620,
            "answer": "Nathaniel Hawthorne",
            "question": "",
            "value": null,
            "airdate": "1984-09-14T12:00:00.000Z",
            "category_id": 98,
            "game_id": null,
            "invalid_count": null
        },
        {
            "id": 626,
            "answer": "F. Scott Fitzgerald",
            "question": "",
            "value": null,
            "airdate": "1984-09-14T12:00:00.000Z",
            "category_id": 98,
            "game_id": null,
            "invalid_count": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Model:

```
public class Clue
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string answer { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
    public int? value { get; set; }
    public DateTime airdate { get; set; }
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    public object game_id { get; set; }
    public int? invalid_count { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int clues_count { get; set; }
    public List<Clue> clues { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Category( int id)
        {
            //  List<Category> clueInfo = new List<Category>();
            List<RootObject> cluess = new List<RootObject>();
            RootObject category = new RootObject();

            category.clueslist  = new List<Clues>();







            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Passing service base url  
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //Define request data format  
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api/category?id=" + id);
                Debug.WriteLine("My debug string here");

                //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                    var ClueResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;




                    //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                     category = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(ClueResponse);

                }






               // return View();
                return PartialView("Category", cluess);
            }
```

Result on view

```
title 
clues_count 

dining out 
20
```

Comment: Are you saying that when you debug the category variable it is not fully populating the child elements. The view does not look like you are ever assigning the category data to the cluess (i.e. what you are passing to the partial view).

Comment: why this line category.clueslist  = new List<Clues>();
var cat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(ClueResponse); is ok
then return return PartialView("Category", cat);